# Any way to see all the methods that don't work at once? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, methods, migration, estimation

I have to estimate the time it takes to update a specific application made for Android 4.4 to Android 10 and I need to see all the methods that are deprecated or not working. Is there any way to see the methods without going file by file? (I'm using Android Studio with Java)

When I build the application I only get one or two types of error at a time, when I correct them I get another one and so on.

Thanks and best regards.

P.S: How long does it take you to update something like that? I'm a junior and I'm a little lost doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, go to Analyze -> Inspect code. After inspecting check maturity there you will have depreciated methods. (Don't forget to change minSdk)
After you will do that it give you method with a warning and you can filter it by having API not support warning